# Run a VBA macro when loading a from

Tags: forms, vba, audio

I'tm trying to do something a little simple, but it's happening something i don't know how to fix.
I have a form in VBA and i wanna play a sound when loading it (it's a custom error window). I'm trying with the following event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    sndWarning
End Sub
```

It plays the sound, but when playing, form becomes empty until sound finish. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to play the sound asynchronously. What is the code of your sndWarning function?

Comment: `sndPlaySound32 "C:\Plantillas Word\error.wav", 0&`  

  Called from  

`Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" ( _
    ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long`

Comment: Change the second parameter from 0& (which means synchronous) to 1& (async). See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PlaySound.aspx for others values available.

Answer (score 0):

As told by @Vincent, changing the  second parameter sovles the question. Thanks dude